# Golang error i is not a type

Tags: go

I have a simple function which takes a variable gets its type and processes it in to a switch but i get an  error :

`i is not a type`

My code looks like this:

```
var whatAmI = func(i, interface{}) { // error is here
    switch t := i.(type) {
    case bool:
        fmt.Println("I'm a bool!")
    case int:
        fmt.Println("I'm an int!")
    default:
        fmt.Println("Don't know type %T\n", t)
    }
}
whatAmI(true)
whatAmI(1)
whatAmI("hey")
```

Am i misunderstanding something here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remove the comma from the function signature and it will work. Try it [here](https://play.golang.org/p/8qawfni8t5).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var whatAmI = func(i interface{}) { // error is here
        switch t := i.(type) {
        case bool:
            fmt.Println("I'm a bool!")
        case int:
            fmt.Println("I'm an int!")
        default:
            fmt.Printf("Don't know type %T\n", t)
        }
    }
    whatAmI(true)
    whatAmI(1)
    whatAmI("hey")

}
```

Also you were formatting the default case print statement incorrectly, so I changed it to match your expected behavior.

Comment: Ohh so its saying `i` is an `interface` that makes so much more sense now :D

Comment: How come you use `reflect.TypeOf(t)` ?

Comment: @Sir This way we can see what type it is. Click on the link I posted and replace `reflect.TypeOf(t)` with `t` and see what happens if we don't.

Comment: so the assignment `t:=i.(type)` assigns "hey" ? Since i uses `t` thats what i get, thats really not what i was expecting lol.

Comment: @Sir Actually you do not need to use reflect, I updated the code to use the type formatter in the string. `t := i.(type)` assigns the type of the interface to `t`. However when using %v as the formatter in the string it attempts to print out the interface, so when the underlying type is a string you will see whatever text it has .

Comment: I'm confused isn't that what i originally had the code looks the same minus the `,` missing in the func of course. EDIT: nevermind just saw you had `printf`